# Stopping a body part from moving

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, constraints, inverse-kinematics

I am working on an animation of a cyclist on a bike, and I encounter a problematic situation while trying to make the rotational movement of the pedal: when I am moving the crank, the chain ring of the bike follows the displacement of the foot, instead of staying still, or rather rotate around the axis.
I have an IK constraint between the cyclist's foot and the pedal to make the pedaling animation, and there is normally no weight between the armature on the mesh yet.

[image: Here is the animation I currently have]

Edit : I have fixed the problem on one side by setting the origin on the center of the pedalboard, but it still moves on the other side.

[image: One side works normally]

Comment: hello, please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Hi Marv, I proposed an edit to your question. Can you see if the terms I used are correct? You can always roll back my edit after it has been approved :) Welcome to Blender SE!

Comment: Hello, thanks for correcting me, it's good for me. And thanks for welcoming me !

Comment: My file is way bigger than 24 mb, how can I upload it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have found a solution to my problem : I had to make a bone parenting between the crank's mesh and the bone instead of Armature deform.